# Apache HTML writing on Raspbian + Pi3

Tags: raspbian, php

I currently have a PI3 on my home network.
With my LAMP apache, I keep the www folder on the USB drive -  let's call it "**/media/USB32/www**". My **user id is Tony**.
I have added my user-id to group www-data.
I can access the www folder for editing from a Windows PC, and I can access it via puTTY.
Apache can show a webpage on it, but **Apache cannot write or update a file** on it via a HTML Form  using Fopen or Fwrite.  Pretty sure my PHP is correct.

The error given is  **fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**
Any idea where my error(s) are?

Comment: We are going to see the code to help further, but the parameter you are passing to fwrite is of the wrong type. having said that this is not a Pi specific question and may be better on our sister site stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome -- but as Steve points out 1) General programming belongs on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/); 2) People expect to see the actual code that doesn't do what you think ("pretty sure my php...") is correct.  Finally, it seems you have lost your original credentials.  If you wish to merge the accounts or something, see the stuff under "My Account" in the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).